# How to change routing in module.ts depending on value from a service?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic4

I have a routing module routing.module.ts file where I want to change the redirectTo path depending on if the user is an admin or not.

My idea is to use a service to capture and hold the value and that will help maintain where it should go but it is not changing. I tried many methods but I can't get it to work. Is there any Ideas?

There is my current code on the routing.module.ts

Any help on how to get it working and explaining the process would be appreciated

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service'

const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: TabsPage,
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          redirectTo: DataService.prototype.isAdmin() ? 'home' : 'dashboard',
          pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
          path: 'home',
          children: [
            {
              path: '',
              loadChildren: () =>
                import('../home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          path: 'dashboard',
          children: [
            {
              path: '',
              loadChildren: () =>
                import('../dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardPageModule)
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          path: 'profile',
          children: [
            {
              path: '',
              loadChildren: () =>
                import('../profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfilePageModule)
            }
          ]
        },
        {
            path: 'menu',
            children: [
              {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: () =>
                  import('../menu/menu.module').then(m => m.MenuPageModule)
              }
            ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

and the data.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  User = {
     isAdmin: false
  }

  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
  ) { }

  setUser(isAdmin: boolean) {
    this.User.isAdmin = isAdmin
  }

  isAdmin() {
    return this.User.isAdmin
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the guard don't make changes in route module it will solve your problem

Example

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SetupToolsGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router,private toaster:ToastrService) {}
  canActivate(): boolean {
    const token = this.authService.decodeToken();
    // parent and sub user access
    if (token && (token.user_type_id === 0 || token.user_type_id === 2 || token.user_type_id === 3 || token.user_type_id === 4)) {
      console.log('norId',this.authService.getNorId())
      if(this.authService.getNorId()!=null){
        return true;
      }
      else{
        if(token.user_type_id===2){
          this.router.navigate(['Admin/admin-dashboard'])
        }
        if(token.user_type_id===0){
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard'])
        }
        if(token.user_type_id===1){
          this.router.navigate(['/superadmin/superadmin-dashboard'])
        }
        if(token.user_type_id===3){
          this.router.navigate(['/tech/tech-support'])
        }
        this.toaster.error('Access Denied! Please follow the steps to create nor file', '', {
            timeOut: 3000
        });
        return false;
      }
    } 
    else {
      if(token)
      {
        this.router.navigate(['access-denied'])
        return false;
      }
      else{
        this.router.navigate([''])
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Adding route guard is best way to handle

Routing module

example path in app.routing.module

```
{
path: 'dashboard',
component: DashboardComponent,
canActivate: [AuthGuard,UserGuard],
```

}

Comment: The route that I showed is on a tab. Does that change anything?

Comment: this is example you can use in ur case